# Should name mangling be used in classes that are inherited by other subclasses?

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance

I'm trying to create classes and subclasses in python with "protected" attributes using name mangling (__). However, when I try to extend the functionality of classes further with different subclasses, I get errors. So when is the appropriate time to use name mangling when the expectation is that both the parent class and the subclasses have unique use cases?

Here is a simple toy example to illustrate the question. Let's say the `Parent` is a realist, so they see the value as it is. The `PositiveChild` sees things in a better light, so they see the value as a positive. The `NegativeChild` is a pessimist, so they see the value as a negative. However, both `PositiveChild` and `NegativeChild` understand how their parent feels, so they have access to the `Parent`'s function.

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None: 
        self.__value = value

    def how_parent_feels(self) -> None:
        print(self.__value)

class PositiveChild(Parent):
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(value)
    
    def how_child_feels(self) -> None:
        print(abs(self.__value))

class NegativeChild(Parent): 
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(value)
    
    def how_child_feels(self) -> None:
        print(abs(self.__value) * -1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This is our function. 
    val = 10

    # Here is our parent. 
    mom = Parent(val)

    # How does she feel? 
    mom.how_parent_feels()
    >>> 10

    # Here is her kids. 
    kid1 = PositiveChild(val)
    kid2 = NegativeChild(val)

    # Do they know how the mom feels? 
    kid1.how_parent_feels()
    >>> 10

    kid2.how_parent_feels()
    >>> 10

    # But how do THEY feel? 
    kid1.how_child_feels()
    >>> AttributeError: 'PositiveChild' object has no attribute '_PositiveChild__value'

    kid2.how_child_feels()
    >>> AttributeError: 'NegativeChild' object has no attribute '_NegativeChild__value'
```

I understand that the name mangling is making both `PositiveChild` and `NegativeChild` to have a `_Parent__value` attribute, and this is what the inherited `how_parent_feels()` method expects and so this works fine. But the respective `how_child_feels()` methods are expecting a `_PositiveChild__value` or `_NegativeChild__value` attribute. So what are your options for re-using name mangled inherited attributes **within subclass specific methods? Is this a misuse of "protected" python attributes and should be avoided altogether?**

Comment: This is a case where you don't want name mangling. Simply use a single underscore for the attribute: `_value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire point of using double-underscore name-mangling *is to prevent name collisions in subclasses*. That's it. So this is precisely the behavior that is intended, what you have demonstrated is the canonical use case for double-underscore name mangling!

Or to be a little more precise, it is to prevent *accidental name collisions*. The whole point is to allow subclasses to define their own `self.__value` variable without having to worry if the parent class is using a name like that! It is to reproduce this one feature of "private" in languages with access modifiers, that is, no accidental name collisions.

It is crucial to understand, though, that isn't *private* though, since these variables are "publicly" accessible.

If you really wanted to use double-underscore name-mangling this way, the straightforward solution is to use the correct variable, which is `_Parent__value`

```
#in a subclass
class PositiveChild(Parent):
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(value)
    
    def how_child_feels(self) -> None:
        # see, all variables are always public in Python
        # this only prevents *accidental* name collisions
        # nothing is stopping you from using this variable
        print(abs(self._Parent__value))
```

If you want to mark a variable as restricted to internal use, you would commonly just use a single leading underscore.

Both of these approaches are equally as "private". Python doesn't have private!

Note, in languages with access modifiers, like Java, if you wanted a variable that wasn't exposed publicly, but was exposed to subclasses, you would use `protected`, so sometimes that terminology is used to refer to this idea in Python.

Comment: So this behavior is totally intentional. Ctrl+F .__ -> ._ it is!

Comment: @JoshuaMincer so see my edit, you can always just *access the variable*, the variable is `_Parent__value`.

Comment: I was aware of potentially using that, but my gut is that would make the code base less maintainable or just add more visual clutter. There's also `self.__value = self._Parent__value`, but that kind of feels like a workaround to ignore an intentional feature. Since there is no "true private" in Python, I think a single underscore will suffice. Thanks!